# Postgresql: How can I duplicate a table with its default values on columns?

Tags: postgresql

Is it even possible to copy a structure from a table without data but with the columns definitions specially like defaults and nullable values ?

This is not working:

```
select * 
into new_ledger_table 
from details_table 
where 1 = 2;
```

Comment: Note that `select ... into ` to create a new table is discouraged (even deprecated) in favor of the standard compliant `create table .. as select ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's what `create table (like ..)` is for:

```
create table new_ledger_table (like details_table including defaults)
```

The `including` part has more options to optionally include constraints and indexes.

Comment: I'll try out and let you know. Thanks.